# Show wrong code address error in g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

Specifically, my C++ file has 61 lines of code open in Sublime Text, when compiling with g++, it gives an error at an incorrect address in Sublime Text.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anpk8.png)

but when opening that file with Code::Block it shows different, there are 115 lines of code
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Pbu.png) and it specifies the right place where the error occurred.
Is this an encoding problem? How to fix it. Thanks

Comment: The code appears to be 'double-spaced' in Code::Blocks. Is Sublime using `\r\n` as a line terminator rather than just `\n`?

Comment: It looks like your code is using some weird convention for end-of-line. I recommend LF, but CRLF should work as well on Windows. Maybe your code uses LFCR or whatever, that confuses Code::Block and GCC.